# How to make Javascript/HTML, stop and wait for user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im making a zork style game in HTML using javascript.

My game currently looks like this,

```
<script>

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
         $(".output").append("
```

Inside the append goes what part of the story you want to print. When the user inputs an answer, A/B/C, then it spits out an answer based on if then.

```
 $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 97) {
            $(".output").append("
```

Problem is it will spit out every single answer I have for that input. I need to find a way for HTML or JS to wait for input then continue on.

Comment: You can try using `prompt()`

Comment: There is no such concept in webpage JS. In the browser, your js is event-driven. That means your code runs in response to events, updates some state and stops running. So to stop and wait, simply quit your function. Save some value in a variable before so next time your function runs you know where to resume from.

Comment: do you mean ,for example ,if user enter a/b/c then do something , if he enter d/f/f do something else?

Comment: I think you need to show more than those 6 lines of code. My guess is you need to add logic....

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$(".temporaryoutput").html(" test ");
$(".temporaryoutput").fadeOut(1000);
$(".output").append("test");
```

**append** add all your answer to the string. **html** will show current answer. You can solve the rest with jQuery.Deferred() - https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/